# Flixel + FlashDevelop as3 tutorial

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, flixel

First of all, I know how to do basic stuff on FlashDevelop such as drawing circles, creating the Hello World sample program, and adding gravity, thanks to online tutorials I found online such as these "https://www.youtube.com/user/blubfaceproductions/videos" and the Hello world sample program, which I posted it before, I can run these sample programs with no problems,I have flixel setted up,but,  I have no idea on how to start using flixel to make games because most of the tutorials I've found online have links broken, PLEASE HELP!!! ANY HELP WOULD BE EXTREMELY APPRECIATED!!!

Comment: http://flixel.org/features.html Demos and source (on Github)

Comment: I think that you are in the wrong place if you are looking for a tutorial ...

Comment: Yeah, I think that you're right, sorry about that akmozo.

Comment: Maybe this could be useful: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn-flixel--gamedev-5843